# Variables values are not coming through `xsl:value-of` in `XSLT 1.0` while browse xml on browser

Tags: xml, variables, browser, xslt-1.0

While browsing XML with associated with XSLT browser not providing anythin `xsl:value-of` I am not transforming i just use browse XML :

**INPUT SAMPLE XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="a.xsl"?>
<students>
    <student>
        <name>Amrendra Kumar</name>
        <class>BCA</class>
    </student>
    <student>
        <name>Sanjeew Singh</name>
        <class>BCA</class>
    </student>
</students>
```

**XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:variable name="students">
        <students>
            <xsl:for-each select="students/student">
                <student name="{name}" class="{class}"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </students>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
                <xsl:element name="script">
                    <xsl:attribute name="src">https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js</xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="script">
                    <xsl:attribute name="src">https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:element>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
            </head>
            <body>
                <h4 style="margin-left:366px; margin-top:68px">List of students</h4>
                <table border="1">
                    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Class</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <!--<td><xsl:copy-of select="$students"/></td>-->
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="$students/students/student/@name"/></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="$students/students/student/@class"/></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When i remove the variable calling part then its working fine, see the result image below without variable try:

[image]

Comment: Even i tried with `exsl:node-set()` but not luck.

Comment: `<xsl:for-each select="studnet">` There are no elements named `studnet`in the XML. Also, if you're defining a global variable, you must start your path from the root.

Comment: Updated question as suggested but again no luck..

Comment: @michael.hor257k Please share processor information where i can debug my xml on Browser.

Comment: A browser is not a good testing environment. Use a processor that returns error messages for your debugging - for example: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94AbWAH

Comment: @michael.hor257k here its work but browser still not supporting. https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94AbWAH/1

Comment: Try using the EXSLT node-set() function in `xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"` namespace instead of `xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"` which only works with Microsoft processors.Note also that some browsers place security restrictions on running XSLT .

Answer (score 0):

In XSLT 1.0, which is what browsers support by default, an `xsl:variable` with contained expressions evaluates to a "result tree fragment" (RTF) and the 1.0 spec does not allow you to query into an RTF using path expressions.

A common workaround to this is to use the extension function exslt:node-set() to convert the RTF to a regular document node. However this extension is not part of the standard and I don't know if it works in every browser. If it doesn't work for you, you need to tell us exactly how you called it and exactly how it failed (this should probably be a new question).

If you want to get away from XSLT 1.0 restrictions, consider using Saxon-JS which offers XSLT 3.0 in the browser (disclaimer: it's my product).